# Firefox and firefox-esr packages in OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: firefox, openbsd

After I issued `sudo pkg_add -vi firefox`, the ftp server responded:

```
Ambiguous:
0. firefox-esr
1. firefox
Enter choice:
```

I didn't know what to choose, so I chose and entered 0.

The installation was successful.

In an Xterm, when I typed `firefox`, the web browser refused to launch.

What happened?

Comment: What shell are you using? You might have to `rehash` so it detects the newly installed program. If that doesn't work, is the executable perhaps called `firefox-esr`?

Comment: @D_Bye: I'm using the default shell, which is ksh. I guess it stands for `korn shell`, right? Yes, you're right: I've to type `firefox-esr` in order to launch the browser. Is there a deft trick that I can use so that I don't have to type `firefox-esr` every time I wish to launch the browser? For example I just need to type `ff` or `fire`.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is with a shell alias: `alias ff="firefox-esr"` in your `~/.profile` should do the trick.

Comment: @D_Bye: Yes, your neat trick works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`firefox` package](http://ports.su/www/mozilla-firefox) installs a binary called `firefox`. The [`firefox-esr` package](http://ports.su/www/firefox-esr) installs a binary called `firefox-esr`. The two are different so that you can install both and choose which one to run on a case-by-case basis. Since you installed `firefox-esr`, you need to run `firefox-esr`.

As the package description indicates, the ESR package contains the [ESR (extended support release) version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/): a version that doesn't have all the latest features but remains stable for a long time with only bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and I must add that `D_Bye`'s neat trick works in my case.